# The column "symbol" shows address instead of function name

Tags: c, linux, perf

Here is my system information.

```
$ uname -a
Linux pjchiou-X550JX 4.16.0-041600-generic #201804012230 SMP Sun Apr 1 22:31:39 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I use a very simple C program to test `perf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myloop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        printf("%d", i);
}

int main(void)
{
    myloop();
    return (0);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -g -o test test.c
```

And then collect a sample with:

```
perf record ./test
```

Finally, show report:

```
perf report
```

But, what I see in the report is like this:

```
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object      Symbol                      
# ........  .......  .................  ............................
#
 9.64%  test     libc-2.27.so       [.] 0x000000000005cb14
 6.17%  test     libc-2.27.so       [.] 0x000000000005bf8e
 5.75%  test     libc-2.27.so       [.] 0x000000000005885e
 5.61%  test     libc-2.27.so       [.] 0x000000000005886b
 5.33%  test     libc-2.27.so       [.] 0x00000000000587b0
 5.28%  test     libc-2.27.so       [.] 0x000000000005b6ff
 5.23%  test     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] n_tty_write
```

Why does the column "*symbol*" show the address instead of function name?

- gdb installed.
- libc6, libc6-dbg, libc6-dev installed.
- Highest access permission.

Comment: Your program is compiled with debugging symbols, but `libc` isn't. So it can't show the names for things in the library.

Comment: you might also want to try running `perf record -g ./test` to get your call graph recorded as well

Comment: Install debug symbols for `libc` if you want names for library functions.  There should be names for at least the `extern` symbol names in libc, though, so that's somewhat strange.  Dynamic linking requires them.

Answer (score 1):

Install debug symbols for libc to get names for library functions with the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
sudo apt-get source libc6-dev
```

Comment: Please see if the following link will help: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1527467#p1527467